# Android bottom-navigation

Tags: android, sdk, android-appcompat

Hi everyone I'm new to android, what I'm trying to add on my learner app is the bottom navigation but I'm getting the error when I build the project:

build.gradle

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.asussonicmaster.nonameapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

`}`

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
}`

What am I doing wrong here,

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Error: [C:\Users\ASUS Sonic Master\AndroidStudioProjects\NoNameApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:21] Invalid instruction 'overrideLibrary', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

Comment: Have your tried to use a more recent build tools version like: buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep the build version, compile version and the google libs at the same version.

Try this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.asussonicmaster.nonameapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
}
```